# Jest - Create React App - Encountered an unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I running jest on a react app created by create-react-app and i'm getting this error:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jest encountered an unexpected token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51994111/jest-encountered-an-unexpected-token)

Comment: the problem still happens

Comment: Unfortunately the screenshot doesn’t provide a lot of information. In order to get help with this, you’ll probably need to post the specific error