# Test failures during styles file imports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jestjs, babeljs

Encountering issues with setting up Jest for React without the use of Create-React-App.

I do not want to use CRA thus sticking with babel and webpack config setup which does work less Jest.

Jest itself is working fine for testing. It only fails when a component has a css/scss file import.

Seen many similar issues here and tried out the solutions but the issue persists.

Could I get some help with what am doing wrong pls? Thanks.

These are some of the solutions I have tried out which is not working for me.

Tried accepted solution and also the other 2 solutions for this:
[jest unexpected token when importing css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54627028/jest-unexpected-token-when-importing-css)

[A Medium Blog with similar solution](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-i-solved-issues-while-setting-up-jest-and-enzyme-in-a-react-app-created-using-webpack-7e321647f080)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51994111/jest-encountered-an-unexpected-token

 Plus a couple of other examples more related to Vue but similar solution.

The error output as follows:

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

Details: 

.some-class {
 ^
```

This is class being tested:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../styles/styles.scss' // line causing issue

const App = () => {

  const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>sample header</h1>
      <p>{`This is in ${env} environment`}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

The Test class

```
import App from "../../components/App";
import React from "react";
import {shallow} from "enzyme";

it('should get a matching snapshot',  () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<App/>)
  expect(wrapper.find('h1').text()).toBe('sample header')
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
});
```

Styles file: styles.scss

```
.some-class {
  color: aliceblue;
}
```

package.json for reference:

```
{
  "name": "tar",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=beta webpack-dev-server",
    "build-prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack -p",
    "build-beta": "cross-env NODE_ENV=beta webpack",
    "test": "jest --config=jest.config.json"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.10.4",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.49",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.0.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.1.0",
    "html-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-cli": "^26.6.3",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.11.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "raf": "^3.3.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.0.2",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/src/tests/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(scss|css|less)$": "<rootDir>/src/tests/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    }
    "transform": {
      "\\.js?x$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest"
    }
  }
}
```

Inside Webpack.config.js (showing partial)

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
      use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
    }
  ]
},
```

Inside . babelrc file

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/react", "@babel/env"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forget to mock `scss` file during test despite having already had `css|less` files there.

To fix that, you have to add `scss` as part of current style file pattern:

`package.json`

```json
{
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      // ...
      "\\.(css|less|scss)$": "<rootDir>/src/tests/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    }
  }
}
```

#### Update

You're currently input `jest` cli with `--config=jest.config.json` which is `json` file which is wrong (it must be `js` file) that ended up the issue.

The right one should be:

```json
jest --config=jest.config.js // `js` not `json`
```

But you have 2 config one in `jest.config.js` and `jest` area in `package.json` file. Please try to use one place instead by either remove `--config=jest.config.js` in CLI or move entire `jest` block into the config file.

Comment: Thanks, tried that and same outcome. Amended the question above.

Comment: Can you share a reproducible repo as well? Sounds like a special case

Comment: Sure: https://bitbucket.org/tamilflix/boiler1/src/master/  Thanks.

Comment: I dropped an update for you regarding to the issue.

Comment: That worked. I was following a tut where the file used was json and not js. It worked in that video. Bit confused. Currently I have added everything to the js file and deleted the json file. Working copy now. Thanks for looking into it.